# How can configure Cisco ASA 5510 to allow access to Web server in DMZ from LAN with port translation?

Tags: firewall, cisco, port-forwarding, cisco-asa

I am trying to configure Cisco ASA 5510 firewall to allow access from LAN to DMZ web server. Web server is located in the DMZ and is using port 8080. I don't want users to type port number every time they try to access the site. So it should forward from 80 to port 8080. I have already done it to outside access. When outside users try to access the web server the port forwarding works but it doesn't work for LAN users. I have used ASDM to do that. Can you help to figure it out? What would be the command to fix that? Thank you.

Comment: Just curious - Why are you running a web service on 8080 in production in the first place? Why not run it on 80 and simplify your config?

Comment: it is not a production enviroment. there are two web servers on that box, one is using 80 and another 8080

Comment: If you forward/translate 80 to 8080, then internal users will never be able to access the web server that exists on port 80.